# CAPTCHA script not working correctly in versions greater than PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, captcha

Below PHP code works fine for PHP 5.2.17 and lower versions (like '7YNd5fG'). But for higher versions than PHP 5.2.17 it is displaying all 7 characters same like 'NNNNNNN' or 'yyyyyyy'.

Please let me know what should I change or add in below code so it works fine in version higher than PHP 5.2.17?

Below function generates random text string with specific chars

```
function get_image_text($length)
{
    $ret_char = "";
    $ret_string = "";
    for($i =0;$i<$length;$i++)
    {
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
        $ret_char = mt_rand(2,3);
        switch ($ret_char) 
        {
            case 1: $ret_char = mt_rand(97, 122); break;
            case 2: $ret_char = mt_rand(48, 57); break;
            case 3: $ret_char = mt_rand(65, 90); break;
        }
        $ret_string.= chr($ret_char);
    }
    return $ret_string;
}
```

get_unique_image.php

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/png");
$str_code=get_image_text(7);
$_SESSION["image_secret_code"] = $str_code;
$im = imagecreatefrompng("../images/unique_image.png");
$white = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);
$font = "arial.ttf";
imagettftext($im, 18, 0, 3, 22, $white, $font, $str_code);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Finally below code is used on page.

```
<img src="./get_unique_image.php" border="0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of PHP are you encountering that issue with?  It works fine for me on 5.5.9, 5.6.19, and 7.0.4.

Because of `$ret_char = mt_rand(2,3);` you will never get lowercase characters; I don't know if that was intentional or not.  Mixing lowercase characters in (even if validation is case insensitive) arguably makes the captcha a bit harder for bots to solve depending on a number of factors.

In any case, I rewrote the function so its a bit shorter and uses `mt_rand()` to pick a random value from the entire list of characters in your set.

```
function get_image_text($length)
{
    // create a string abcdefg....XYZ
    $chars = implode('', array_map('chr',
                 array_merge(range(97,122), range(48, 57), range(65, 90)))
    );
    $ret_string = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i)
    {
        // pick a random offset from character string
        $ret_string .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
    }
    return $ret_string;
}
```